# Delphi Image DLL not working in Azure

Tags: delphi, azure, canvas, bitmap, draw

We have a dll to process some images of our software.
I recently created an application in golang and it uses this DLL, everything works perfectly in a testing environment, but in azure, the images created are all black, I do not know if it is a delphi limitation, OS, azure, if someone has a tip..
Below the code that generates the image, even a simple code with only a Draw, the image turns black.

```
AOut := 'test.bmp';
vBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
vBitmap.Width := 2399;
vBitmap.Height := 3337;
vBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
vBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
vBitmap.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
vBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,2399,3337));
vBitmap.SaveToFile(AOut);
```

An aditional information, if I get the information of height and width of the canvas I have everything 0 in the azure, but in the other machines the dimension is correct.

Comment: Do some debugging.

Comment: Debuggin in Windows API calls in a DLL in azure? It's hard to achieve.

Comment: Not at all. Use trace debugging.

Comment: The code you show makes no sense. How are `vBitmap`, `vBitmapParedes` and `ACanvas` related?

Comment: Sorry, I changed too much in the code, at the time of putting it here I screwed up...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's how I got the information of the incorrect size of the canvas, I think it is related to this, however any call to drawing api: `Canvas.FillRect` or, `canvas.LineTo`, for example, does not print anything in the bitmap.
Currently in the tests I realized that `canvas.TextOut` works normally, even with different colors.

Comment: Keep debugging then. Why did you stop there?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not stop, I thought I'd get some direction or tip, but thanks for your support :)

Comment: It's hard for us to help because we don't have a complete program or even ready access to the execution environment. I suggest you continue debugging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand your point, you're right.

Comment: The code you show, still doesn't compile. Stop wasting our time on correcting typos and copy - paste **actual** code into your question. Complete methods so we can see local vars and method parameters.

Comment: Be specific about WHICH Azure service you're running on. VM/Cloud Services/App Service? If the latter, you're probably running into the GDI sandbox restrictions - more here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox (CTRL-F for GDI32)

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg sorry, I just wanted to show an example, that a simple bitmap does not work there, @evilSnobu explained why.

Comment: @evilSnobu That's it, it's explained, I use app services, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure **App Service** has some sandbox limitations, especially around GDI. As a result, some (or all) of your User32/GDI32 API calls fail.

> #### Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions
>
> For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that **most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked.**
>
> For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web applications after all).

See [this wiki document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) for more.