# Delphi DLL debugging not working in Azure

Tags: azure, delphi, dll, com

I currently have 2 development environments, 1 setup on my Windows 10 notebook and the other on a Virtual Machine (VM) hosted on a Windows server. In both environments I can attach and debug my COM DLLs without any problems.

We are now moving all our VMs to Azure and I have setup a 3rd dev environment. Everything seems to be working fine except, I cannot debug my DLLs anymore. It looks like the host app attaches to my DLL but it does not stop at any of my breakpoints.

My project options are exactly the same in all environments i.e. Optimization=false, debug info=true, include remote debug symbols=true, etc.

The application is rather old: 32-bit, written in Delphi 2010, running on SQL Server 2008.

I found this article that suggests there are issues with 32-bit applications in Azure but I am not sure if it could be applicable to me. [Delphi Image DLL not working in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365465/delphi-image-dll-not-working-in-azure)

Does anybody have experience in setting-up COM+ DLL debugging on an Azure VM? Are there anything specific that must happen? Anything on the COM+ Application that might be an issue (security, identity, activation)? I have played around with the COM+ Application properties but did not have any luck.

Comment: The link is about Azure *App Service* which does have serious limitations. In an Azure VM, there should not be any particular issue than with another VM. Have you tried in a local VM of yours (for example with Hyper-V)?

Comment: I started over again. Rebooted all my machines. Recompiled all my DLLs, Redeployed the DLLs in Component Services, restarted COM application, etc. Not sure what was wrong but after doing everything again, it started to work... A day in the life of a programmer....